# Как получить данные переменной из потока

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt, qt-designer, qtimer

У меня есть код, задача которого в зависимости от полученных данных из **`.txt`** документа подсветить `label`.

В **`.txt`** документе может лежать:

- `Left` - тогда подсветить нужно текст **`LEFT`**
- `Right` - тогда следует подсветить **`RIGHT`**
- `Center` - тогда подсвечиваем **`CENTER`**

Только данные в **`.txt`** файле постоянно меняются, поэтому я использую еще один поток, который постоянно считывает данные из моего файла.

Главный вопрос как мне получать эти данные в других местах и собственно подсвечивать текст?

Также как мне завершить работу потока вместе с закрытием окна?

```
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import threading

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(291, 207)
        self.left = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.left.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 40, 51, 101))
        self.left.setObjectName("left")
        self.center = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.center.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 40, 51, 101))
        self.center.setObjectName("center")
        self.left_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.left_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 40, 51, 101))
        self.left_3.setObjectName("left_3")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.left.setText(_translate("Dialog", "LEFT"))
        self.center.setText(_translate("Dialog", "CENTER"))
        self.left_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "RIGHT"))
        
class show(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(show, self).__init__(parent, QtCore.Qt.Window)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.parent = parent
    
    


def eye_info():
    while True:
        txt = open("eye_direction.txt", "r")
        eye_direction = txt.read()
        txt.close()
    print("Thread stop")
        
        
    
    
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = show()
    t = threading.Thread(target=eye_info, args=())
    t.start()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: А зачем вообще вы используете питоновские потоки? Они бесполезные, всё равно всё в GIL упирается

Comment: @Inventor GIL не блокирует интерфейс - питоновские потоки имеют массу полезностей.

Comment: @eri он блокирует потоки и никогда 2 потока одновременно работать не будут. Тогда вопрос зачем они нужны, если всё равно 1 ядро трудится

Comment: ну тут вы не совсем правы. он блокирует только питонский код. если выполняется сишная функция (например кутэ отрисовывает окошко на си++) то эта функция не блокируется gil

Comment: @eri а что эта сишная функция не в питоновском потоке будет выполняться? В нём же и будет и пока она в этом потоке выполняется ничего другого не происходит

Comment: @Inventor пока сишная функция выполняется в одном питоновском потоке gil свободен и может быть захвачен другим питоновским потоком. если конечно криворукие программисты ничего не задедлочат

Comment: @eri нет, когда выполняется сишная функция внутри питоновского потока это равносильно тому что выполняется обычный питоновский код внутри этого потока. Интерпретатору неважно какой код и каким образом выполняет поток, он не передаст контроль выполнения другому потоку не загасив текущий. Иначе это становится не потокобезопасным, что пропагандирует cpython

Comment: @Inventor sleep(10000) не блокирует  второй поток например

Comment: @Inventor а для потоко безопасности есть мьютексы

Comment: @eri когда gil видит sleep(10000) он просто затыкает этот поток пока время не пройдёт и отдаёт контроль другим

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для решения вашей задачи вам не нужен дополнительный поток.

> Класс **QTimer** предоставляет повторяющиеся и однократные таймеры.

```
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
#import threading

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(291, 207)
        self.left = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.left.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 40, 51, 101))
        self.left.setObjectName("Left")                             # Left 
        self.center = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.center.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 40, 51, 101))
        self.center.setObjectName("Center")                         # Center
        self.left_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.left_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 40, 51, 101))
        self.left_3.setObjectName("Right")                          # Right

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.left.setText(_translate("Dialog", "LEFT"))
        self.center.setText(_translate("Dialog", "CENTER"))
        self.left_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "RIGHT"))
 
 
#class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_MainWindow):                     # QDialog  !!!
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
#        self.parent = parent

        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.left, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.center)
        layout.addWidget(self.left_3)
        
        self.labels = [self.left, self.center, self.left_3]
    
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.eye_info)
        self.timer.start(2000)


    def eye_info(self):
#        while True:
        with open('eye_direction.txt', mode='r') as inputfile:
#            txt = open("eye_direction.txt", "r")
            eye_direction = inputfile.read()
#            txt.close()
        #print("eye_direction")
        for label in self.labels:
            if label.objectName() == eye_direction:
                label.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            else:
                label.setStyleSheet("")
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
#    t = threading.Thread(target=eye_info, args=())
#    t.start()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]